# Power Supply AC/DC Power OK Signal Control

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics

I will combine 4 ac/dc converter (1000 W) by using  parallel operation mode to create 4 kW unit. I will add 4 LEDs to observe converter signal health.

There are digital output including POWER ON SIGNAL, AC GOOD SIGNAL and POWER OK SIGNAL. I added related piece of datasheet. And I added a design. Can you say that whether it is true or not.

1. I want to ask that can I use these digital outputs to drive directly 5V LED or do I have to use a external microcontroller (like Arduino) to determine HIGH/LOW state and drive LED by usign external microcontroller(like Arduino) digital outputs?
2. And which of AC/DC converter digital outputs (POWER ON SIGNAL and POWER OK SIGNAL) should I use to determine that output DC is OK? Can you advise me a way?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is "a 5 V LED"?

Comment: @Transistor almost certainly an LED with built-in current limiter, intended to be connected directly to a 5V supply.

Comment: "Maximum sink current is 100mA" your answer is right there. Connect a LED and a 330R resistor (or calculate your own) to +5V and you're done. 9Whatever  a "5V LED" is, it's almost certainly a LED and a resistor; as a way of selling a resistor at a hefty margin.

Answer (score 0):

The Power OK line tells you if both Power On and AC Good are OK.  So that's the one you want.

It can sink up to 100mA, which is more than enough for a small indicator LED.  Remember that low is OK, high is not OK.  So wire the LED between 5V and the signal output.